# Curvature operator on tensor

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Picture below is from Topping's Lectures on the Ricci flow. I can't understand the (2.1.2).

What I know: for any vector field $Z\in \mathfrak  X(M)$, there is
$$
R(X,Y)Z = \nabla _Y\nabla _X Z  - \nabla _X  \nabla _Y Z  + \nabla _{[X,Y]}Z 
$$
Similar, if $\omega\in \mathfrak X(M)^*$ which is dual space of $\mathfrak  X(M)$, there is
$$
R(X,Y)\omega = \nabla _Y\nabla _X \omega  - \nabla _X  \nabla _Y \omega  + \nabla _{[X,Y]}\omega 
$$
Therefore, assume $A=A_{i_1,...,i_k} dx^{i_1}\otimes ...\otimes dx^{i_k}
$,
there is
$$
\nabla^2_{Y,X} A(W,Z,...) = (\nabla_Y\nabla _X A)(W,Z,...) -
(\nabla_{\nabla_X ~Y} A )(W,Z,...)  \\
=\nabla_Y[X(A(W,Z,...))]
-
\nabla_YA(\nabla_XW,Z,...)-\nabla _Y A(W, \nabla_XZ,...)
-...  \\
~~~~~~
-(\nabla_XY)(A(W,Z,...)) 
+A(\nabla_{\nabla_X~Y}W,Z,...)
+A(W, \nabla_{\nabla_X~Y}Z,...) 
+...
$$
similar, I know $-\nabla^2_{X,Y} A(W,Z,...)$. But I don't know how to get the second, third, forth lines of (2.1.2).

> [image]

Comment: Second is def of Riemann curvature.

Comment: Third is same as second because as Topping explained $R(X,Y)f=0$ for all smooth functions $f$ and $A(W,Z, ...)$ is a function.

Comment: if you want to calculate it directly let me know.

Comment: @C.F.G  Thanks  for your help. I have  directly calculate it,  it is a little complex  :-)